# Issue : Cut off the description when Add event to google calendar from .ics file

Tags: c#, icalendar

when I add the event in the google calendar from .ics file then not coming full description.

Here .ics file data

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ICalendarCreator//NONSGML//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20200916T024900
DTEND:20200917T124900
SUMMARY:test
LOCATION:test
DESCRIPTION:Hi, asd as asd as ksjak jdaksjd kljaskdj lkajdsk ljsakjd lkjsadkl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd lkajskd jlaksjd lkajskd jlkaj lkajsd jalsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a kjaljd jasd alkjd lakjdlk jalkdj lkajdlk aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk daksj alkd jalks iuash aksj lkasjdl alkjd lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj laksdk lalkds jlaksjd lkajldk jalkdj lkajd lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasjdlkas sd as asd as ksjak jdaksjd kljaskdj lkajdsk ljsakjd lkjsadkl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd lkajskd jlaksjd lkajskd jlkaj lkajsd jalsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a kjaljd jasd alkjd lakjdlk jalkdj lkajdlk aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk daksj alkd jalks iuash aksj lkasjdl alkjd lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj laksdk lalkds jlaksjd lkajldk jalkdj lkajd lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasjdlkas hiasddk ajkdljalk alksj klajsdk ljalksdj lkasd klajskd ljaksjd lkasjd lkajsdkl jaskj sadsa dasd asdas dasd asd skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl  sad asdasd asd sd as end
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

HERE out put in google calendar
[image]

end is last word in the description in .ics file. But not coming in google calendar.

Anyone have idea?  any limition ? solution ?

**Updated**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ICalendarCreator//NONSGML//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20200916T024900
DTEND:20200917T124900
SUMMARY:test
LOCATION:test
DESCRIPTION:Hi asd as asd as ksjak jdaksjd kljaskdj lkajdsk ljsakjd lkjsad
 kl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd lkajskd jlaksjd lkajskd jlkaj lkajsd ja
 lsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a kjaljd jasd alkjd lakjdlk jalkdj lkajdlk
  aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk daksj alkd jalks iuash aksj lkasjdl alkjd 
 lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj laksdk lalkds jlaksjd lkajldk jalkdj lkajd 
 lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasjdlkas sd as asd as ksjak jdaksjd kljaskd
 j lkajdsk ljsakjd lkjsadkl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd lkajskd jlaksjd
  lkajskd jlkaj lkajsd jalsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a kjaljd jasd alkj
 d lakjdlk jalkdj lkajdlk aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk daksj alkd jalks i
 uash aksj lkasjdl alkjd lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj laksdk lalkds jlaks
 jd lkajldk jalkdj lkajd lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasjdlkas hiasddk aj
 kdljalk alksj klajsdk ljalksdj lkasd klajskd ljaksjd lkasjd lkajsdkl jaskj
  sadsa dasd asdas dasd asd skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl skdj lka
 sdkl  sad asdasd asd sd as end asd as asd as ksjak jdaksjd kljaskdj lkajds
 k ljsakjd lkjsadkl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd lkajskd jlaksjd lkajskd
  jlkaj lkajsd jalsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a kjaljd jasd alkjd lakjdl
 k jalkdj lkajdlk aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk daksj alkd jalks iuash aks
 j lkasjdl alkjd lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj laksdk lalkds jlaksjd lkajl
 dk jalkdj lkajd lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasjdlkas sd as asd as ksjak
  jdaksjd kljaskdj lkajdsk ljsakjd lkjsadkl jaskjd lkjaskdj lkasjdkl jlasjd
  lkajskd jlaksjd lkajskd jlkaj lkajsd jalsjd lkjaskdj lkajs lkasj jalsj a 
 kjaljd jasd alkjd lakjdlk jalkdj lkajdlk aiui akdjaksjdlk lkdlkajd lalk da
 ksj alkd jalks iuash aksj lkasjdl alkjd lkasdk ljalkdj lkajsdk ljalkdj lak
 sdk lalkds jlaksjd lkajldk jalkdj lkajd lkajskdl jaskdj lkasdklajsdj lkasj
 dlkas hiasddk ajkdljalk alksj klajsdk ljalksdj lkasd klajskd ljaksjd lkasj
 d lkajsdkl jaskj sadsa dasd asdas dasd asd skdj lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl skdj 
 lkasdkl skdj lkasdkl  sad asdasd asd sd as end
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Not with this type of description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ics file lines need to be 'folded' if they are longer than 75 characters. See the specification: https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-1-content-lines.html.

> Lines of text SHOULD NOT be longer than 75 octets, excluding the line
> break. Long content lines SHOULD be split into a multiple line
> representations using a line "folding" technique. That is, a long line
> can be split between any two characters by inserting a CRLF
> immediately followed by a single linear white-space character (i.e.,
> SPACE or HTAB). Any sequence of CRLF followed immediately by a single
> linear white-space character is ignored (i.e., removed) when
> processing the content type.

Comment: Thanks for answer. working first example using folded technique but I have updated the question with one more example and it is not working.

Comment: Oh found, I was checked on add calendar from received mail. This way is not working because I think, limitation of query string